# Is there a way to transfer an app from a device to another one (App no longer on the app store)?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, iphone

I have and use Photosynth regularly on an iPhone 4s.
I bought a 5s last week and when i wanted to install the app on it i realised that the app isn't on the app store anymore.

Is there a way to transfer it from the 4s to the 5s ?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to sync both to iTunes, transfer purchased items from the 4S to iTunes when syncing and then transfer it to the 5S like you would a song or movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have purchased/downloaded the app with your Apple ID, you would still be able to download the app from the "Purchased" section of the App Store even if the app has been removed from the shelves.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to do a back up of the 4s. Then you want to follow these steps:

[image]

Once you've finished that, you want to load the iPhone 5s with the backup.

[image]

And then you should be good to go. These are from apples website: [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201269)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good suggestion, i was about to follow what you said eventhough i really dislike using iTunes. Fortunately @Nescio24 posted a very useful tip. His solution works fine. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyhow. Cheers